# Object not found in R

Tags: r

I'm brand new to R and I'm using it for an Econometrics homework. I have imported a data set from excel and i need to run a regression with just the intercept, but R will not recognise the variable vio, which is the column header, no matter what I try.

```
install.packages("readxl")
library("readxl")
getwd()
setwd("Users/yuryglazman/Documents/My Documents/Econometrics")
guns <- read_excel("Guns.xlsx")
guns

yr86 <- guns[c(10),c(1:13)]
yr86

myreg = lm(vio~1)
summary(myreg)
```

The error message is

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'vio' not found
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `lm(vio ~ 1, data = yr86)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
myreg = lm(vio~1,data=yr86)
```